# Crash when viapoint is used for route calculation or navigation

Tags: c++, ios, swift, skmaps

I have tried to add a `SKViaPoint` using both methods, using SKRouteSettings’s `viaPoints` array and also using the `SKRoutingService`’s `addViaPoint:` method. I get this crash for both:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::length_error: vector
```

Any idea why?

Comment: We're looking into the swift example

Comment: The issue is under investigation by our dev team- we confirm we've discovered the problem using the SKViaPoint